# How to run some alias command in bash's non-interactive mode

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I want to run some alias command in bash's non-interactive mode. But seems Ubuntu ignore BAHS_ENV. How can I make it work? `la` is a alias command. And I tested in other linux. it is work fine. Just Ubuntu not work.

`BASH_ENV=~/.profile bash -O expand_aliases -c la`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just found out because the origin .bashrc provided by Ubuntu have some code like below to prevent the script run in non-interactive mode. so why my alias not work. It's work now just need to move aliases higher then this block

```
#If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
 *i*)
 ;; *)
 return;;
esac
```

Comment: any idea why they put it there?

Comment: you mean why they put the block there? I also dont know :)~